# Selenium Web driver/java session should expires after 20min

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Selenium Web driver/java. I have a scenario where i login to a web site and if the site is idle for 20 minutes then it should redirect the user back to the login screen. can anyone give me a sample example. Appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Since after 20 minutes of inactivity, the application should log out, it will have to go back to the log in page. That means you have to check for visibility of Login button after 20 minutes.

Use the WebDriverWait to wait for 20 minutes after login and then check if Login button is visible.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getWebDriver(), 1200);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("loginButton")));
```